# Merging cells of a table populated with MongoDB collection data?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

im currently using a `forEach` function to loop through my collection called `environments` to be displayed in an HTML table, but since there are multiple rows with the same version, how do i go about merging just those cells? I know i can use `rowspan` to merge cells, but my issues stems from using a `forEach`. using `rowspan` in a loop like that causes obvious issues, hence my question...

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Version</th>
      <th scope="col">Region</th>
      <th scope="col">Contact Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Date Added</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% environments.forEach(function(environment){ %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= environment.version %>
      </td>
        <td>
          <%= environment.region %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= environment.contact %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= environment.date %>
        </td>
     <% }); %>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm trying to take entries in a MongoDB collection like this:

```
{
"version" : "1.0",
"region" : "CA",
"contact" : "Smith",
"date" : "2019.09"
}
```

many entries have `version 1.0` so when i loop through the collection to be displayed in a table, it shows up as something like:

```
Version   | Region| Contact Name | Date Added
----------------------------------------------
version 1 | CA    | Smith        | 2019.09
version 1 | CO    | Kovach       | 2019.08
version 1 | WA    | Scott        | 2019.10
version 1 | OR    | Lee          | 2020.01
version 1 | HI    | Franco       | 2020.01
```

but does anyone know how to change it so that it doesn't list `version 1` over and over again? I can't figure out how to do it because there is also a few that are `version 2`, etc. i want it to look like:

```
Version   | Region| Contact Name | Date Added
----------------------------------------------
          | CA    | Smith        | 2019.09
          | CO    | Kovach       | 2019.08
version 1 | WA    | Scott        | 2019.10
          | OR    | Lee          | 2020.01
          | HI    | Franco       | 2020.01
          | CA    | Chow         | 2019.09
          | AZ    | Reynolds     | 2019.08
version 2 | MI    | Cooper       | 2019.06
          | CO    | Gooden       | 2020.01
          | HI    | Parr         | 2020.10
```

Comment: In order to do that with a rowspan, you need to know how many rows will show `version 1` ahead of time, so you'll need to look ahead and count.  You could get a similar effect by storing the last version value in a variable, and only putting "version 1"  in the table when it is different than the previous value, otherwise leave the cell empty.

Comment: @Joe if I were to go about it the first way, say there are 10 version 1's, 15 version 2's and 15 version 3's, how would that work in a forEach loop? if I do rowspan=10, that only applies to version, whereas version 2 and 3 would take up 15 rows each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leave the field empty when it's repeated:

```
<% 
var currentVersion = "";
environments.forEach(function(environment){ %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= currentVersion != environment.version ? environment.version : "" %></td>
    <td><%= environment.region %></td>
    <td><%= environment.contact %></td>
    <td><%= environment.date %></td>
  </tr>
<% 
currentVersion = environment.version;
}); %>
```

That should be enough, but if you need to add rowspan you can use a script:

```js
var rowspan = 1;
var rows = document.querySelector("table").rows;
for (var i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // Go through all rows from last to first
  if (rows[i].cells[0].innerText == "") { // If content is blank
    rowspan++; // increase rowspan
    rows[i].deleteCell(0); // and remove from table
  } else {
    rows[i].cells[0].rowSpan = rowspan; // Else set rowspan
    rowspan = 1; // and reset value
  }
}
```

```css
td { background: #333; color: white; padding: 1px 4px; font-size :13px; font-family: segoe ui }
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>version 1</td><td>CA</td><td>Smith</td>   <td>2019.09</td></tr>
<tr><td></td>         <td>CO</td><td>Kovach</td>  <td>2019.08</td></tr>
<tr><td></td>         <td>WA</td><td>Scott</td>   <td>2019.10</td></tr>
<tr><td></td>         <td>OR</td><td>Lee</td>     <td>2020.01</td></tr>
<tr><td></td>         <td>HI</td><td>Franco</td>  <td>2020.01</td></tr>
<tr><td>version 2</td><td>CA</td><td>Chow</td>    <td>2019.09</td></tr>
<tr><td></td>         <td>AZ</td><td>Reynolds</td><td>2019.08</td></tr>
<tr><td></td>         <td>MI</td><td>Cooper</td>  <td>2019.06</td></tr>
<tr><td></td>         <td>CO</td><td>Gooden</td>  <td>2020.01</td></tr>
<tr><td></td>         <td>HI</td><td>Parr</td>    <td>2020.10</td></tr>
</table>
```

Another option would be pre-process the entries:

```
<% 
var currentVersion = "", count = 1;
for (i = environments.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // From last to first entry
 if (environments[i].version == currentVersion) {
   count++; // Same version? Increase rowspan
 } else {
   count = 1; // New version? Reset
 }
 currentVersion = environments[i].version;
 environments[i].count = count; // add counter to dataset
}
currentVersion = "";
environments.forEach(function(environment){ %>
  <tr>
    <% if (currentVersion != environment.version) { %>
      <td rowspan="<%= environment.count %>"><%= environment.version %></td>
    <% } %>
    <td><%= environment.region %></td>
    <td><%= environment.contact %></td>
    <td><%= environment.date %></td>
  </tr>
<% 
currentVersion = environment.version;
}); %>
```

Comment: wow thank you! this was so much more than i was expecting, i really appreciate your taking the time to help me out!